# Visual Studio 2013 always rebuilds in Release mode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I have a C++ solution that depends on 3 other solutions. If I build the project in *Debug* mode, everything works as expected, only the modified files and solutions get rebuilt. If I change the mode to *Release*, the project gets rebuilt every time, including the dependencies.

How can I avoid rebuilding everything in *Release* mode?

Comment: Have you checked for differences between the Debug and Release configurations?  In particular, is there a build event that could be causing problems?

Comment: There are no _Pre-Build_ or _Pre-Link_ events, there is a _Post-Build_ event that involves copying some files, but it's the same for both _Release_ and _Debug_ configurations. I did not spot any other obvious issues with the _Release_ config.